# How to display data from related tables in Details Action in View MVC4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to display details view from related tables using ViewModel.

So i've created the Details Action method but it's not working.

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {

        IQueryable<EntryViewModel> query = (from cat in _db.Categories
                 join en in _db.Entries on cat.Id equals en.CategoryId
                 where en.Id == id
                 select new EntryViewModel
                 {
                     Title = en.Title,
                     Username = en.Username,
                     Password = en.Password,
                     Url = en.Url,
                     Description = en.Description,
                     Category = cat.Name
                 }).AsQueryable();

        return View(query);
    }
```

I am getting this error, that cannot figure out solution.

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[App.ViewModels.EntryViewModel]',
 but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'App.ViewModels.EntryViewModel'.
```

View:

```
@model PasswordCloudApp.ViewModels.EntryViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
<legend>EntryViewModel</legend>

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Username)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Username)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Password)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Url)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
</div>
</fieldset>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post your view razor content please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is of type `PasswordCloudApp.ViewModels.EntryViewModel` but you are passing from the controller an `IQueryable<EntryViewModel>`.

Since you expect a single item given an id, you can change your controller code to return that single item (and maybe return a 404 if not found):

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{

    EntryViewModel model = (from cat in _db.Categories
                            join en in _db.Entries on cat.Id equals en.CategoryId
                            where en.Id == id
                            select new EntryViewModel
                            {
                                Title = en.Title,
                                Username = en.Username,
                                Password = en.Password,
                                Url = en.Url,
                                Description = en.Description,
                                Category = cat.Name
                            }).FirstOrDefault();

    if (model == null) return HttpNotFound();

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set model in your view like:

```
@model IQueryable<PasswordCloudApp.ViewModels.EntryViewModel>
```

Comment: Where i was looking. Thanks. But now have another error.  'System.Linq.IQueryable<PasswordCloudApp.ViewModels.EntryViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'Title' and no extension method 'Title' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<PasswordCloudApp.ViewModels.EntryViewModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Any toughts?

Comment: using your elements like:@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.FirstOrDefault().Title)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have `PasswordCloudApp.ViewModels.EntryViewModel` bound to with your view but you are passing Iqueryable so while returning the view from the action either you associate FirstOrDefault() of the result or change the `@model IQueryable<PasswordCloudApp.ViewModels.EntryViewModel>` in the view.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {

        IQueryable<EntryViewModel> query = (from cat in _db.Categories
                 join en in _db.Entries on cat.Id equals en.CategoryId
                 where en.Id == id
                 select new EntryViewModel
                 {
                     Title = en.Title,
                     Username = en.Username,
                     Password = en.Password,
                     Url = en.Url,
                     Description = en.Description,
                     Category = cat.Name
                 }).AsQueryable();

        return View(query.FirstOrDefault());
    }
```